# Spark on Yarn with custom Python fails in client mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda, hadoop-yarn

We used to submit our own Python (conda) environment with `spark-submit` (with `yarn` as master), as described e.g. [here](https://henning.kropponline.de/2016/09/24/running-pyspark-with-conda-env/). We do this, because the default Python in the cluster is still Python2.

A few weeks ago, this stopped working - but interestingly only in `client` mode - `cluster` mode still works.

WORKS:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./anaconda3/venv/bin/python \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./anaconda3/venv/bin/python \
    --archives /path/to/venv.tar.gz#anaconda3 \
    my_spark_program.py
```

does NOT work:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/path/to/venv/bin/python \
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./anaconda3/venv/bin/python \
    --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./anaconda3/venv/bin/python \
    --archives /path/to/venv.tar.gz#anaconda3 \
    my_spark_program.py
```

Likewise, starting an interactive PySpark Shell (with the above options) does not work.

The error that is thrown is: Python versions in Driver and Worker do not match - the Driver is reported to have Python Version 3.6, whereas the Workers have Python Version 2.7. So it seems that the Worker environment is not correctly set up in `--deploy-mode client`?

We have Spark Version `2.3.0` and Yarn (Hadoop) version `2.6.0`.

Any pointers as to why that may have stopped working?

Comment: how many nodes? have you install python 3 for all nodes?

Comment: nodes available - not sure. nodes in use: one node for worker, in cluster mode another for driver. Python in cluster is Python2 - Python3 is not generally available, which is why we distribute it through ``--master yarn --archives my_venv.tar.gz`` - see question above and linked article explains how that (is supposed to) work.

Comment: @akoeltringer it is quite a while, but have you found the solution ?